# Specify absolute path to chromedriver for Selenium in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to convert my java code to ruby and I need to set absolute path to my chromedriver exe. I have it working in java using this code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver");
```

How do I replicate it in ruby? Or is there a gem that I can include that will set the chromedriver in the right path?

Comment: You want to open chrome browser using Ruby bindings of `selenium` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do